# Hiding the Address Bar of a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm writing this app, in which I allow a user to use his Facebook credentials to login. As part of that FB login, I display a UIWebView to present the user with a FB login screen.
The UIWebView shows, besides the user/login UI, a standard Address/Navigation bar.
I think that is ugly, and I want to get rid of it.
Although I can imagine, that there is a good reason why it is impossible/discouraged (notably: spoofing), I would feel much better if I would be able to present the user only with widgets that are necessary for the scope of functionality.
I have Googled a while, but all I have found was irrelevant or outdated. 
Can any of you help me?

Comment: "The UIWebView shows, besides the user/login UI, a standard Address/Navigation bar" A UIWebView has no "standard Address/Navigation bar". It just shows the web content.

Comment: my bad: the 'UIWebView' that is called (and it really looks like a UIWebView) is the result of a FBSDK method.